# Rails where query for authorisation not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to create an authorisation method (offer_authorised) for a page (show). Unfortunately it seems that the where query is not working properly with the code i have.

I can still access the page with all of the users, although i should be only able to access it if the user_id equals the current user id.

```rb
Offer.where("id = ? AND user_id = ?", 2, 2) 
  Offer Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "offers".* FROM "offers" WHERE (id = 2 AND user_id = 2) LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Offer id: 2, amount: 950, status: "hyväksytty", rental_id: 1, user_id: 2, created_at: "2019-09-19 12:21:22", updated_at: "2019-09-21 11:08:52">]>
```

On the console side it seems to return properly the correct record.

Here is my Offers controller.

```rb
class OffersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :offer_authorised, only: [:show]
    before_action :set_offer, only: [:accept, :reject]
    before_action :is_authorised, only: [:accept, :reject]

    def create
        rental = Rental.find(offer_params[:rental_id])

        if rental && rental.user_id == current_user.id
            redirect_to request.referrer, alert: 'Et voi tehdä tarjousta omasta kohteestasi.'
        end

        if Offer.exists?(user_id: current_user.id, rental_id: offer_params[:rental_id])
            redirect_to request.referrer, alert: 'Voit tehdä vain yhden tarjouksen tällä hetkellä.'
        end

        @offer = current_user.offers.build(offer_params)
        if @offer.save
            redirect_to my_offers_path, notice: 'Tarjous tehty.'
        else
            redirect_to request.referrer, flash: {error: @offer.errors.full_messages.join(', ')}
        end
    end

    def accept
        if @offer.odottaa?
            @offer.hyväksytty!
            @offer.rental.update(active: !@offer.rental.active?)
            flash[:notice] = 'Tarjous hyväksytty.'
        end
        redirect_to request.referrer        
    end

    def reject
        if @offer.odottaa?
            @offer.hylätty!         
            flash[:notice] = 'Tarjous hylätty.'
        end
        redirect_to request.referrer    

    end

    def show
        @offer = Offer.find(params[:id])
        @rental = @offer.rental_id ? Rental.find(@offer.rental_id) : nil
    end


    private

    def offer_authorised
        redirect_to dashboard_path, 
            alert: "Sinulla ei ole oikeuksia" unless Offer.where(id: params[:id], user_id: current_user.id)
    end


    def set_offer
        @offer = Offer.find(params[:id])
    end

    def is_authorised
        redirect_to root_path, alert: "Sinulla ei ole tähän oikeuksia." unless current_user.id == @offer.rental.user_id
    end

    def offer_params
        params.require(:offer).permit(:amount, :rental_id, :status)
    end
end
```

Comment: Try debugging the values for `params[:id]` and `current_user.id`.

Comment: which controller method is not behaving you want it to?

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
Offer.where(id: params[:id], user_id: current_user.id)
```

will always evaluate to `true` because it returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` – even if the relation evaluates to an empty array. Therefore your method will never trigger the redirect.

Instead, use a method that evaluates to `true` or `false` like [`ActiveRecord.exists?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F):

```
Offer.exists?(id: params[:id], user_id: current_user.id)
```

Comment: If `User` class does have `has_many :offers` relation, you can also check this using the `current_user` object - `current_user.offers.exists?(params[:id])`